# Am I considered a non-resident of California?

Tags: united-states, taxes, california

I need help in determining if I qualify as a non-resident in the state of California:

- I physically work in an office in CA
- It is a W2 job
- My primary domicile is outside of CA
- I spend more than half of the year outside of CA (I work from home most days)
- On the days I do go to the office, I commute across state lines to the office.

The purpose of this question is so that I can confirm that I am not liable for state income tax. I discussed my situation with my employer, and they recommended that I mark myself as exempt from California taxes due to the fact I am not a resident and thus do not owe CA taxes.

Obviously my employer's recommendation is based on my assertion that I am a non-resident. That is what I am not *certain* about. From the information I can find, I believe I am indeed a non-resident, based on the criteria I listed above. How can I confirm?

Comment: Bugbear for clarity of question wording: the word 'resident' has absolutely no meaning without specifying exactly which government agency/department/entity you want an answer contextualised to. Here, implicitly, you mean "am I non-resident according to CA's FTB?". The federal IRS may have a different opinion, as may (for example) CA's DMV, when residency matters for driving purposes. Other federal agencies e.g. DHS, differ yet again (more relevant to aliens / non-citizens). Every entity defines 'resident' differently.

Answer (score 14):

You're most definitely liable for CA State tax. You have income sourced to California, and California is going to want its share of it. Your residency status is irrelevant to that.

The only difference residency status makes is to income not sourced to California (your earnings while outside CA, or capital gains, etc). Anything you earned while working physically in California is sourced to California and taxed by it.

You may get credits for taxes paid in your home state, if you paid any, or get credits in your home state for CA taxes paid.

Comment: The official California page that discusses nonresident tax obligations: https://www.ftb.ca.gov/file/personal/residency-status/part-year-and-nonresident.html

Comment: Wow! All these years I thought you only got taxed based on the state you live in. Doesn't directly affect me as I have lived and worked in the same state for ~ 36 years. But still.

Comment: It's a common misconception, but sourcing of income is not a new concept and is a critical component of tax law and tax policy. CA specifically is one of the more aggressive states when it comes to revenue collection. New York is even more so with cracking down specifically on remote work.

Comment: To clarify: only part of the OP's income is sourced to California (i.e. wages for the days working from the CA office) and part is sourced to the OP's home state (i.e. wages for the days working from home). So if the OP is a CA nonresident, as it appears he is, the OP will need to divide their income when filing CA taxes.

Comment: It's not unusual for athletes to *lose* money on games played in California given how taxes are computed. Cam Newton famously paid about $137,000 in California taxes on games for which he was only paid $51,000. (California does not determine how much of your income is California sourced based on how much you were paid for work done in California for a single employer because that could be trivially evaded by, for example, allocating bonuses to non-California work.)

Comment: This is a pretty common state of affairs any time you have a major metropolitan area near a state border: Chicago is commuting distance from parts of Indiana, Philly is commuting distance from parts of New Jersey, NYC is commuting distance from (other) parts of New Jersey, etc.

Comment: @user102008 - indeed, even back in the 1970s my father kept track of which days he worked downtown in a city, and when he was on travel. The city had a wage tax for work in the city, and it did not apply to work outside the city.

Comment: How exactly is "income sourced" defined? Because my company has offices all over the state and all over the world. They are not exclusively a California company. So, is it my physical presence in an office building in CA? That means the income is sourced there because I worked from that office? What if I travel for a few weeks to another office in another state? This seems very ambiguous

Comment: @JamesWierzba yes, your physical presence in an office building in CA. If you traveled for a few weeks to another office in another state - income earned while working in that state would be sourced to that state. Generally, the rules of income attribution for earned income are that such income is sourced first to the jurisdiction where it is earned, and second to the jurisdiction where the employee is resident. So if you live in Nevada, and work physically in California - the income is sourced to California because it's earned there and CA has first dibs on taxes...

Comment: ... it's actually not at all ambiguous, but rather very deterministic.